# Error 404 cuando creo una nueva página en wordpress

Tags: wordpress, nginx

estoy intentando crear página en wordpress y cuando direcciono a esa página obtengo error 404, estoy usando Nginx como servidor web. He probado con la siguiente configuración pero no obtengo resultados.
location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
...
}
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es complicado saber que causa ese error, trata de regresar el .htaccess de tu sitio wordpress al .htacces por default, si no funciona prueba a desactivar tus complementos y actualizar tus permalinks

Comment: Ya lo hice, no funciona, he investigado todo el día y ninguna solución me ha funcionado